# Nopcommerce Seo friendly route

Tags: c#, url, nopcommerce

I'm using Nop Commerce.my question is about GenericUrlRouteProvider.
If is possible, i have a url like **www.mysite.com\SeoFriendlyCountry\SeoFriendlyProduct**
in the GenericUrlRouteProvider class,there is only one Sename.
How can i have more than one sename for generate my friendly url.

I apologize for my poor English writing.

Thanks

[BEST REGARDS]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add separate SeName for country base. As per my work you only need to embed the country name when you are generating the product url like:

```
<a href="uk/@(Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = "testpro" }))"
```

Nopcommerce always test the last keyword of URL in his route if it's found that's good otherwise goes to the SeoRoute class under

> Nop.Web.Framework

In SEO route class it check the last keyword of url in the database so above style will work easily.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.But I want change url to this way: www.mysite.com\iran\computers-and-laptops.